# How to scroll to selected item in a select box

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-2

In my application when I person selects an item at the bottom of the select box the area is reloaded with another select box. My problem is when the select box is loaded it scrolls to the top instead of scrolling to the selected item

observe here
http://www.jaunna.com/question/Add

UserID: **top**

Pass: **t**

Comment: +1 for a moment I thought SO had a new sister-site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the selectedIndex to the value you want selected with JS and it should automatically be shown as default.

You're link doesn't work.

Comment: sorry..login info is this UserID: top, password: t

Comment: Your JS doesn't allow for multiple selections so you can try changing that, also your javascript recreates the containing div which it also shouldn't (either destroy the old one or simply update it's contents). Try fixing that those first